# AssertionFailedWithCauseError when executing instrumentation tests on Travis CI

Tags: android, travis-ci, android-espresso, android-testing

I am running instrumentation tests based on [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/) 2.2.2 in my [Android project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/tree/travis-ci). All tests **succeed** when I run them **locally** against different devices such as a Nexus 5 phone (Android 6.0.1) and a Nexus 9 tablet (Android 7.1.1) via the following command:

```
./gradlew testDebug connectedCheck --stacktrace -PdisablePreDex
```

Once I run the same task on Travis CI with this [configuration](https://travis-ci.org/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/jobs/494467892/config) then two of the tests **fail** with a confusing error message:

```
CityInfoFragmentTest > renderCityInfoWithStandardZone[test(AVD) - 4.3.1] FAILED 
    android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 

    'with text: is 
    "Since May 1, 2014 only vehicles with a green sticker are allowed to drive into the low emission zone."
    ' doesn't match the selected view.

    Expected: with text: is 
    "Since May 1, 2014 only vehicles with a green sticker are allowed to drive into the low emission zone."
```

As you can see the actual and expected texts do match!?!

- [Related build log entry](https://travis-ci.org/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/builds/494467891#L1376-L1378)

---

I am not using Espresso 3.0.2 because there is a [bug which prevents running tests on certain devices](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113560556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines [1500 & 1501](https://travis-ci.org/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/builds/494467891#L1500-L1501) as well as [1562 & 1563](https://travis-ci.org/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/builds/494467891#L1562-L1563) in the build log explain what went wrong. Here's a snippet:

> Expected: with text: is "Since May 1, 2014 only vehicles with a green sticker are allowed to drive into the low emission zone."
>
> Got: text=As of May 1, 2014 only vehicles with a green sticker are allowed to drive into the low emission zone.

The expected string begins with "Since" but the actual string begins with "As of"

Are you hardcoding strings in your test? If so, you shouldn't :)

Comment: Awesome finding! It looks like I [forgot to update the tests](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/commit/fbeff55af98c23be0f4eb36d24b77e1fccd9224e) at the time I introduced the "since" or "as of" prefix. Thank you very much. - With regards to the console output which I quoted: it looks like as if Espresso prints **expected** text twice. Might be a bug somewhere in the [`ViewMatcher.withText()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.java#513). Do you agree?

Comment: Glad I could help. Not sure what's going on with that console output to be honest.

Comment: To me it looks like as if Espresso prints out **twice** the **expected** text instead of first the **expected** text and then the **actual** text as it is done in the build log which you referenced. If I find time to create an example I will check if the wrong output is reproducible and if it is specific to a certain version of Espresso.

Comment: Meanwhile, I checked the [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=AssertionFailedWithCauseError) but could **not** spot such an issue there.

Comment: Bear in mind that you're using an older version of Espresso so this may have been fixed already.